# Laravel - query part of a integer and boolean value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

In my database I have **id** column which can contain **integer, string, integer + string** value. like, check this image:

https://ibb.co/2KNJzVW

As you can see on the **id** column I have something like this value:

> product id
> PPAETRABN018283

So, On the input box (my search form) -

If I enter **product** I can get the result as there is **product id** value as **id**.
If I enter **PPAE** I can get the result as there is **PPAETRABN018283** value as **id**

BUT

If I enter **182** I can't get any result, although I use `LIKE`. Can you tell me why?

And

I have another column called **availability** which contain **true** and **false** as boolean. If I do search with **true** I can get result but I do search with **false** I can't get the result. Can you tell me why?

**Here is my code:**

```
$trimmed_array = $request->all();
$whereLike = $whereIn = $where = [];

foreach( $trimmed_array as $k => $v ) {
    if( $k !== 'page' && $k !== 'projectToken' && $k !== 'userId' ) {
        if( !empty( $v ) )  {
            if( is_numeric( $v) ) {
                $whereIn[] = [$k, (int) $v];
            } elseif( trim( strtolower($v)) == 'false' || trim(strtolower($v)) == 'true') {
                $where[] = [$k, $v ];
            } else {
                $whereLike[] = [$k, 'LIKE', '%'. $v .'%' ];
            }
        }
    }            
}

$projectToken = $request->input('projectToken');
$userId = $request->input('userId');

$this->set_connection( $projectToken, $userId );

$get_project_id =  DB::connection('mysql')->table('projects')->where('token', $projectToken )->get(['id_project'])->first();
$collection = 'products_' . $get_project_id->id_project;
$collection = 'products_105';

$search = DB::connection('mongodb')->collection( $collection );

if( count( $whereIn) ) {
    foreach( $whereIn as $array ) {
        $key = $array[0];
        $value = (int) $array[1];
        $search->whereIn($key, [$value]);
    }
} 

if( count( $whereLike) ) {
    $search->where($whereLike);
}

if( count( $where ) ) {
    foreach( $where as $arr ) {
        $key = $arr[0];
        $value = (bool) $arr[1];
        $search->where($key, $value);
    }
}

$search = $search->paginate(100);
return response()->json( [ 'product_value' => $search ], 200);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases we use `LIKE` with wrapping `%`, for example:

```php
$needle = ...; // What to find (User's input).
$query = ...;

$query->where('myColumn', 'like', '%' . $needle . '%');
```

And if you search in multiple columns, try:

```php
$needle = ...;
$query = ...;

// List search target.
$columns = ['myFirstColumn', 'myOtherColumn'];
$pattern = '%' . $needle . '%';

foreach ($columns as $name) {
    $query = $query->orWhere($name, 'like', $pattern);
}
```

> **Note** that if `where(...)` method's third-parameter is not set, Laravel automatically uses "`=`" condition-operator in the query by default, while above uses "`LIKE`" instead.

Comment: Thanks though I found the solution. Its working with `orWhere`